# clone process support in python

Tags: python

Is there any support of the syscall [`clone(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clone.2.html) (*not* `os.fork`) in Python?  I want to play with Linux namespaces under Python but it seems that there is not a lot of information about it.

Edits:

I think ctypes with libc is the answer but I'm still not having any success. fork works without problems since it doesn't have any argument then this code work:

```
from ctypes import *

libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")
libc.fork()
```

With clone I'm trying this:

```
from ctypes import *

def f():
    print "In callback."
    return 0

libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")

f_c = CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(f)

print libc.getpid()
print libc.clone(f_c)
print get_errno()
```

Clone actually has this signature:

int clone(int (*fn)(void *), void *child_stack,
                 int flags, void *arg, ...
                 /* pid_t *ptid, struct user_desc *tls, pid_t *ctid */ );

I still need to pass *child_stack and flags but have no idea how to do it. Any help?

More Edits:

I got this now:

```
from ctypes import *

def f():
    print "In callback."
    return 0

libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")

f_c = CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(f)
stack = c_char_p(" " * 1024 * 1024)
libc.clone(f_c, c_void_p(cast(stack, c_void_p).value + 1024 * 1024), 0)
```

This actually works but I imagine I making a big hole in my system with the stack, there is a cleaner way to do this?

Edits:

Almost done, adding the correct flag for newpid:

```
from ctypes import *

libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")

def f():
    print libc.getpid()
    return 0

f_c = CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(f)
stack = c_char_p(" " * 1024 * 1024)
libc.clone(f_c, c_void_p(cast(stack, c_void_p).value + 1024 * 1024), 0x20000000)
```

This is not runnable just for root, and print a nice 1.

And following this post the stack seems to be fine: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxPidNamespaceSupport

Comment: If you use just the `CLONE_NEWPID` flag (`0x000200000`), the child process will be instantly reparented to the parent process's init, so the parent process won't be able to wait for the child. You probably want to use `signal.SIGCHLD|0x000200000` if you want to wait for the child process in the parent process. (You have to specify some signal, and `SIGCHLD` is the obvious candidate.)

Answer (score 10):

Well, finally I think I got the answer, is just usign [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html) with libc,

This is a simple proof of concept:

```
from ctypes import *

libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")

# Create stack.                                                                                                                                                                            
stack = c_char_p(" " * 8096)

def f():
    print libc.getpid()
    return 0

# Conver function to c type returning an integer.                                                                                                                                          
f_c = CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(f)

# We need the top of the stack.                                                                                                                                                            
stack_top = c_void_p(cast(stack, c_void_p).value + 8096)

# Call clone with the NEWPID Flag                                                                                                                                                          
libc.clone(f_c, stack_top, 0x20000000)
```

This has to be run by root.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have "fork() but with new namespace" semantics, you can directly call the `SYS_clone` syscall instead. Note that if you do so, the `os.getpid()` method will return the wrong process ID in the child because glibc caches the process ID and doesn't know about the `SYS_clone` invocation to invalidate its cache.

Assuming x86_64 (`NR_clone == 56`, `NR_getpid == 39`), you can call `libc.syscall(56, signal.SIGCHLD|0x000200000, 0 0 0)` to "fork", and then `libc.syscall(39)` to get the current PID of the "forked" child process.

Comment: "From glibc version 2.3.4 up to and including version 2.24, the glibc wrapper function for getpid() cached PIDs, ... since glibc version 2.25, the PID cache is removed: calls to getpid() always invoke the actual system call, rather than returning a cached value." ([getpid(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html))